# Programmatically create segue between a ViewController and a NavigationController?(Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, ios8

I want to create a segue manually.First I wanted to make a custom segue in storyboard and code id,but it's deprecated in Swift.So I want to ask you guys,how can I create a segue programmatically between a UIViewController and a UINavigationController.Pay attention,not between two UIViewControllers....I want that if a variable it's true than create the seague between the ViewController and NavigationController,and show the NavigationController,otherweise if that variable is false nothing happens.
Can somebody help me please?

Comment: show us what you have tried